# MediaPlayerErrorDomain Xode =-11800

Tags: ios, xamarin

Currently I am programming my first xamarin cross platform app.
I trying to add a video background and in the internet I found the following guide: https://www.junian.net/xamarin-forms-video-background/

But when I try to test it on my iOS emulator, I got the following error:

**2019-01-12 02:27:54.095262-0800** RelationshipAppNew.iOS[1587:10185] [Playback] Using  to resolve error Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-101), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023a4a20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-101 "(null)"}}

**2019-01-12 02:27:54.095800-0800** RelationshipAppNew.iOS[1587:10185] [Playback] ❗️Resolution for item  could not resolve error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-101), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023a4a20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-101 "(null)"}} with resolution error: (null)

**2019-01-12 02:27:54.096289-0800** RelationshipAppNew.iOS[1587:10185] [Playback] ❗️Playback failed with error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-101), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023a4a20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-101 "(null)"}}, not resolving (canResolve: NO, allowsItemErrorResolution: NO)
2019-01-12 02:27:54.190780-0800 RelationshipAppNew.iOS[1587:10185] Notification: NSConcreteNotification 0x60000238a580 {name = MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification; object = ; userInfo = {
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}";
}}

**2019-01-12 02:27:54.252088-0800** RelationshipAppNew.iOS[1587:10185] FinishReason: PlaybackError

This is the code of the iOS renderer:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using RelationshipAppNew.Controls;
using RelationshipAppNew.iOS.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MediaPlayer;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Video), typeof(VideoRenderer))]
namespace RelationshipAppNew.iOS.Renderers
{
    class VideoRenderer : ViewRenderer<Video, UIView>
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController videoPlayer;
        NSObject notification = null;

        protected override void 
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Video> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                InitVideoPlayer();
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                notification?.Dispose();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Subscribe
                notification = MPMoviePlayerController.Notifications.ObservePlaybackDidFinish((sender, args) =>
            {
                /* Access strongly typed args */
                Console.WriteLine("Notification: {0}", args.Notification);
                Console.WriteLine("FinishReason: {0}", args.FinishReason);

                Element?.OnFinishedPlaying?.Invoke();
            });
        }
    }

    void InitVideoPlayer()
    {

        var path = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, Element.Source);

        if (!NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video not exist");
            videoPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController();
            videoPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
            videoPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
            videoPlayer.RepeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
            videoPlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            SetNativeControl(videoPlayer.View);
            return;
        }

        // Load the video from the app bundle.
        NSUrl videoURL = new NSUrl(path, false);

        // Create and configure the movie player.
        videoPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(videoURL);

        videoPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
        videoPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
        videoPlayer.RepeatMode = Element.Loop ? MPMovieRepeatMode.One : MPMovieRepeatMode.None;
        videoPlayer.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        foreach (UIView subView in videoPlayer.View.Subviews)
        {
            subView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        }

        videoPlayer.PrepareToPlay();
        SetNativeControl(videoPlayer.View);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (Element == null || Control == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == Video.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            InitVideoPlayer();
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == Video.LoopProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var liveImage = Element as Video;
            if (videoPlayer != null)
                videoPlayer.RepeatMode = Element.Loop ? MPMovieRepeatMode.One : MPMovieRepeatMode.None;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think I made something wrong with the MPMoviePlayerController, but I can't find the failure.

Comment: I just plugged your exact render code into a project and it worked as expected, so the issue is likely somewhere else. What emulator are you running it on? Maybe something with the particular video? Double check the name, path, build action, and also make sure it is a video format that is supported.

Comment: There is more detail within that 11800 error that you should add to your question, but in general it is a problem with playing the video in the matter that you have chosen, but without the detail the issue is just a guess

Comment: @jgoldberger I connected visual studio with my mac over network and I test it with iOS 12.1. The Emulator is the standard-Emulator from Visual Studio. The file format is mp4. Maybe the resolution of the video is to big.

With "NSFileManager.DefaultManager.FileExists(path)" I alredy check if the video is found. And he found the file everytime.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I've edited my post and added more informations about the error.

Comment: If you drag and drop the video into the emulator's Photos app, can you play the video.

Comment: I can't add files to the emulator with Drag & Drop.

Comment: Have you tried other videos?

Comment: Yeah I tried smaller mp4 videos